# Git revision not containing word

Tags: regex, git

In specifying the revision *youngest commit in branch X not containing word WIP*, using the Git `<rev>^{/<text>}` syntax, I've tried to use the regex answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/2062510).

For instance, I'd expect this command to checkout the commit "My feature foo", when all the younger commits in the branch X contain the word WIP in their message such as "WIP feature bar":

```
git switch --detach X^{((?!WIP).)*}
```

However, even with bash escape characters, the pattern apparently doesn't match any commits at all.

[edit]

As pointed out by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) the correct syntax is simply:

```
git switch --detach 'X^{/!-WIP}'
```

Comment: Please do add your expected result too. It'll help

Comment: What exactly does "it does not work" mean? What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: Try `'X^{/!-WIP}'`. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtlttextgtemegemHEADfixnastybugem).